# Why does this countup?

Tags: javascript, recursion

this is a JS exercise on recursion I did on FCC. I still can't understand why it counts up instead of down. The answers on the FCC forum has so far not been of much help.

```
function countup(n) {
  if (n < 0) {
    return [];
  } else {
    const countArray = countup(n - 1);
    countArray.push(n);
    return countArray;
    }
 }

console.log(countup(5));
```

This is the result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].

Following the logic of the code I expected the
result to be [5, 4, 3, 2, 1] instead.

I still can't, for the life of me, get why it counts up and not down.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The result starts with `0`, not with `1`. Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger? When will `countArray.push(n);` be reached for the first time? [Found](//google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+js+explain+recursion+that+counts+up+numbers) the exact function explained here: [Recursive count in JS what happen after reaching 0?](/q/66225803/4642212).

Comment: get 5 pieces of paper ... start at 5 ... write the number on a piece of paper and place it on the table ... write 4 on next piece of paper and place it on the previous piece ... repeat three more times ... read the numbers from the stack of papers

Comment: Okay guys, I got it! Thanks, everyone!

Comment: Fun fact: you can write the whole recursive function also as `const countup=n=>n>0?countup(n-1).concat(n):[];`.

Answer (score 1):

The first `countup(5)` results in the `else` running, and:

```
const countArray = countup(n - 1); // <--- recursive call here
countArray.push(n);
```

So `countup(4)` runs - doing the same thing, and so on, until `n` is -1. At that point, an empty array is returned, and the stack looks like this:

```
countup(5)
  countup(4)
    countup(3)
      countup(2)
        countup(1)
          countup(0)
            countup(-1) <-- this returns an empty array
```

The execution of the function call `countup(0)` resumes, and it sees:

```
// const countArray = countup(n - 1);
const countArray = []; // substituting return value
countArray.push(0); // substituting argument
return countArray;
```

So `0` gets pushed to the array, and `[0]` is returned.

Then `countup(1)` resumes, and it sees:

```
// const countArray = countup(n - 1);
const countArray = [0]; // substituting return value
countArray.push(1); // substituting argument
return countArray;
```

So `[0, 1]` gets returned. The pattern continues. At the end, the final return value is  `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.

Comment: So if I got this right: the `countArray.push(n)` is executed only after an  empty array is returned?

Comment: Yes, because the code is: `const countArray = countup(n - 1); countArray.push(n);` The recursive call of `countup(n - 1)` is before `countArray.push(n)`, so that's the order it occurs in